# Running IRT with correlated items and many missing values

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

I'm hoping to run an IRT analysis where I have a couple families of items, and each person has answered one question from each family. Are there R packages for doing something like this? I've looked at options like `hIRT` but this seems to only account for individual level covariates, not item level covariates. I'm expecting the data to look something like this:

| 1a | 1b | 1c | 2a | 2b | 2c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  | 0 |  |  |
|  | 0 |  |  | 1 |  |
| 1 |  |  |  |  | 1 |

where each person answers one of 1a, 1b, and 1c, and one of 2a, 2b, and 2c.

Comment: You can use Stan or JAGS in R to model such data.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking of doing something like that, though I wasn't sure if a bayesian approach was the only choice. (That would be a fine option, just wasn't sure.)

Comment: Using a Bayesian approach you can model the missing values and put some priors on them. I am not sure how else you can deal with the missing values.

Comment: some IRT-R packages, such as `ltm`, `mirt` and `TAM` implement maximum likelihood estimation, that can handle missing values. What is the relationship among the items within a family? Might be a relationship that is typically modeled by testlet models, linear logistic test models or copulas...

Comment: @Tom - I'm basically hoping to model questions like "what's the derivative of ax^2" where a is picked from a list, so I expect that there will be correlation between those items. I'm not familiar with some of those types of models you mentioned, so I'll look into them, thanks@

Comment: @Matt - ok, so we're talking about automated item generation.

Comment: @Tom - I guess maybe eventually, but right now I'm thinking about something like "what's the derivative of ax^2" where a is selected from e.g. [-1, 1, 5, 3.5] so there would just be 4 versions of that problem.